# .dockerignore isn't working on subdirectory... still ends up in the image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Basically I have a structure like the following:

```
project/
  src/
     .unwantedsub/
  .dockerignore
```

Sure enough, whenever I build the image .`unwantedsub/` ends up in the image.

I've tried the following:

```
.unwantedsub
.unwantedsub/
*.unwantedsub/
src/.unwantedsub
src/.unwantedsub/
./src/.unwantedsub
```

Still shows up in the image. Nothing else is in the `.dockerignore`. I'm making sure to destroy the image and make a whole new one, so isn't an issue of looking at the same one. (I did that a few times).

What does work is moving the `.dockerignore` into that directory and then `.unwantedsub` works. Was hoping to avoid a `.dockerignore` in every subdirectory though.

Anyway to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following `.dockerignore`:

```
src/.unwantedsub
```

works well. I've made a complete working example. Run it in an empty directory.

```
$ mkdir -p src/.unwantedsub                                                                                                                                                                               
$ echo src/.unwantedsub > .dockerignore
$ echo FROM debian > Dockerfile
$ echo ADD . /data >> Dockerfile
$ docker build -t test  .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/2 : From debian
 ---> de8b49d4b0b3
Step 2/2 : Add . /data
 ---> a15b1ddf86e4
Successfully built a15b1ddf86e4
Successfully tagged test:latest
$ docker run -it test:latest                                                                                        
root@b3c8ffc73b7f:/# ls -l data/src/
total 0
```